# Getting data from a webpage in PHP

Tags: php

I need my PHP script to download data from a webpage (on another server) - let's say I need to check newest questions on stack overflow :).

What is the best way to do this? What I have thought of is:

1. Making an http request for a webpage and getting particullar text
   from the html code (if php can do something like this),
2. Running a bash script or a C++ app that would do something like in a) (if php
   can't do this) and saving data to txt file, from which php would
   read it.

I personally prefer the first option and if not only C++, bash or python script.

Of course if you know any better ways to do this I will be happy to know them :). These two ways I listed above are only my suggestions on how I think it could be done.

Comment: Check stackoverflow rss feed

Comment: PHP has `file_get_contents` and `curl` that you can use to download web pages, and a number of HTML parsing libraries that you can use to get data from the page. What's keeping you from doing #1?

Comment: Well, I'm just reading about RSS now. It might be a really good idea, but I must just read how to do it. Thanks for your answers ;).

Comment: **1.** open this: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds, **2.** parse it, **3.** use it. Of course if the real world application is **not** SO and doesn't have its own RSS/syndication feed, you will need to parse the webpage using something else - as Barmar says, `file_get_contents()` plus an inbuilt parser should do the trick, something like `xpath` would do.

Comment: i recommend curl above file_get_contents, because a lot of webhosting companies dont allow it and disable it on the server side, due to the unsafe approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what type of webpage is it. In case of Stackoverflow, use RSS.

In general case, you can use `$remote_page_source = file_get_contents('http://...')` method and parse it using regexp etc.

The easiest way is to use API, but I assume that remote webpage does not offer it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do they have an API?. For stackoverflow the API documentation is here https://api.stackexchange.com/docs and you should use this https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions to get the latest questions.